# Combine data from like named rows into one summed row, eliminating the multiple rows

Tags: excel

In the example below 1100 and Salaries, are actually separate columns.  I want to combine all of the 1100 codes and sum the data into one like named row. And repeat for 2100 codes,resulting 8 lines of data summed into 2 lines of data.  See below.

```
1100    SALARIES     $1,017,558 $1,001,728 $938,026  $(63,702)-6.4%
1100    SALARIES     $237,325    $223,110    $225,622    $2,512     1.1%
1100    SALARIES     $30,715     $35,000     $35,000     $-     0.0%
2100    BENEFITS     $94,859     $96,378     $91,697     $(4,681)   -4.9%
2100    BENEFITS     $116,234    $138,774    $193,864    $55,090    39.7%
2100    BENEFITS     $156,002    $155,823    $196,448    $40,625    26.1%
2100    BENEFITS     $3,488      $3,430      $13,847     $10,418    303.8%
2100    BENEFITS     $7,474      $7,349      $12,916     $5,567     75.8%
3000    OTHER INSTRUCTIONAL COST     $2,865      $3,714      $3,714      $-     0.0%
3001    PURCHASE SERVICES    $-      $-      $-      $-     0.0%
5500    PROFESSIONAL DEVELOPMENT     $2,690      $2,491      $2,367      $(124) -5.0%
6000    MATERIALS / SUPPLIES     $19,983     $13,290     $12,625     $(665) -5.0%
8200    EQUIPMENT ADDITIONS  $3,353      $2,401      $2,281      $(120) -5.0%

        TOTAL    $1,692,546      $1,683,487      $1,728,407      $44,920    2.7%
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how many categories you have and if they change often. If they are fairly stable, you can just use formulas, for example:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A8,1100,C1:C8)
```

This will add all the numbers in column C where the values in column A are 1100.

If your table is large or changes often, you could also use a pivot table.